# A Chain Stretch . .

Tags: chain

As a "ten speed" (Raleigh) is my main source of transportation . . .

Does any one know of a chain manufacturer who makes a shrunken chain (slightly smaller pitch) so the chain actually begins to fit the sprockets as it stretches (wears) ? ? ?

Comment: All modern chains come in a single pitch (width however varies).  If you have worn your drive train to a different pitch, you can try and track down used changes (with a slightly longer pitch) or you will need to unfortunately replace.  If your drive train is new (or otherwise within spec), a new chain will be at the correct pitch.

Comment: I have never heard of such a chain, and it doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: It's often been claimed that Campagnolo chains are slightly too short. Measurements don't back that up.

Comment: A short-pitch chain will simply run badly even on a new cassette for the same reasons an over-elongated chain wears out cassettes faster.  The stresses will be focussed on one roller that makes good contact and the others are just along for the ride.

Comment: If you have ever worked as a machinist . . . a pro

Comment: . . . see @Paparazzi

Comment: What about "Huret" ? ? ? Do they still make chains ? ? ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A chain, especially one for a "10 speed" (5 rear cogs) is going to use a pretty basic chain that only costs about $10 to replace. You should just replace it when needed. Having the pitch be too small and having the chain stretch to fit the cogs would just put extra wear and tear on the cogs and possible affect shifting performance. A chain is a consumable item and should be replaced when required.

Comment: You can do a lot with ten dollars on a ten speed these days . . . this is the decade of change . . . lets see what we can do to insure the future for  generations to come

Answer (score 1):

Would not reduce wear. The wear short plus the wear long is the same total wear.

You typically get 2-3 chains per cassette. Even a proper length chain is a shortened chain on a worn cassette.

Comment: I would beg to differ . . . wear short is moved into tolerance . . . the same   technique is used in lapping (engine valve, etc.) to give parts a better fit (purchase)

Comment: @HughMoore A purchase the cam is not worn